# Azure best plan choice for ASP.NET MVC, wcf service and SQL Server database?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-roles

I want to create Front End: **ASP.NET MVC**, Web Service: **WCF** and Back End: **SQL Sever 2012**.
SQL Server Database size required 50GB now.

Should i publish asp.net site and wcf serivce on **Azure Web Site** or **Azure Cloud Service**?

For **Azure Virtual Machine** how it will charged they charged wcf hosting on VM also?

They charged install SQL Sever 2012 on VM and configure database on VM?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no requirement for complex multi-tier app, asp.net site & wcf service can be hosted in azure web sites. Here is a brief sample : http://genuinebasil.com/blog/wcf-service-over-azure-web-site/